# m2eclipse fails to index remote repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, indexing, repository

I'm trying to use Maven's dependency management (in Eclipse) for a Cascading based map/reduce project.  I've updated the project's POM with the Cascading repository info

```
<repository>
  <id>conjars.org</id>
  <url>http://conjars.org/repo</url>
</repository>
```

and enabled indexing in the repository view.  However, eclipse is unable to index this repository and reports

```
Error
Mon Nov 12 19:02:18 CST 2012
Unable to update index for conjars.org|http://conjars.org/repo
```

I'm not behind a firewall, so proxy issues shouldn't enter the picture.  I'm running eclipse on Mac OS X (mountain lion).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  It's my own misunderstanding of Maven (I a newbie), the m2eclipse plugin, and how/if remote 3rd party repositories support indexes.

Specifying my group/artifact/version IDs explicitly (for the Cascading packages), rather than relying upon keyword searches within the Eclipse plugin, to resolve my dependencies solved the problem.